# programmatically get SharePoint Fast search content sources

Tags: web-services, fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

Need help to complete my Csharp program.
   I have four content sources in my farm. I need to get all the content sources and start full crawl if the content source is idle.

What is the best way to do it. 
 Please can someone point me to a good article for Sharepoint search object model / fast search object model.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be powershell in my eyes, example here: http://aghy.hu/AghyBlog_EN/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=a2d07745-f748-4d3b-9c0d-8a15ff7fea35&ID=174&Web=53c3b316-5b05-47ab-9779-74b30194e68b

If you want to use c# then you can use the code example from this post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anavijai/configure-a-crawl-schedule-for-enterprise-search-content-source-in-sharepoint-2010/